# Number of Observation and variables are not equal in data frame R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, rows

I am running the **abc**(Approximate Bayesian Computataion) library in R. I am using the *human* dataset from *abc.data*. I run below line of code for model selection example which is working fine.

```
modsel.it <- postpr(stat.voight["italian",], models, stat.3pops.sim, tol=.05, method="mnlogistic")
summary(modsel.it)
```

I save the above mentioned *human* dataset data frames(**stat.voight, models, stat.3pops.sim**) as  **.csv(**st,mod,stat3**)** respectively and run the same line of code for .csv files. It works fine but I get an error when I run the **postpr** functions as mentioned below

```
t <- postpr(st["italian",], mod, stat3, tol=.05, method="mnlogistic")
```

It gives me an error of **Error: 'Number of summary statistics in 'target' has to be the same as 'sumstat'**.
Then I checked the **str** (structure) of the actual dataframe and then open I saved as .csv. The one I saved as **.csv**  is changed from the **actual** dataframe. Below shown are the images of the **actual(stat.voight)** and  **.csv(st)** dataframes. I want to change my dataframe **st** dataframe be same as dataframe**stat.voight**. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write.csv()` function has a default argument of `row.names = TRUE`, which writes the row names as the first column in the CSV. If you set `row.names = FALSE`, the row names will not be written to the file.

That said, the objects have a number of attributes that aren't written to the output files with `write.csv()`. As such, you're better off using `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` to serialize these objects and reload them into R.

Comment: Yes that works... I have to unlist dataframe mod and to change it as a vector and starts working.. thanks